# Interface props declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, typeerror

I'm new on Typescript and I'm stuck with some interface props. there is an error that says "*Property 'services' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AkkordionProps[]*", I don't understand because I see services on my interface declaration so, my head is lost now.

Here is the main component calling the BusinessPage component:

```
<BusinessPage services={services} />
```

and here is the BusinessPage.tsx component:

```
  export interface AkkordionListProps {
  services: {
    name: string
    services: {
      name: string
      content: string
      link: string
    }[]
  }
}

export interface AkkordionProps {
  services: AkkordionListProps[]
}

export const BusinessPage = (services: AkkordionProps[]): JSX.Element => {}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`BUsinessPage` is react component. React always expects an object as a prop instead of array:

```js
import React from 'react'

export interface AkkordionListProps {
    services: {
        name: string
        services: {
            name: string
            content: string
            link: string
        }[]
    }
}

export interface AkkordionProps {
    services: AkkordionListProps[]
}

export const BusinessPage = (props: AkkordionProps): JSX.Element => {
    return <div></div>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4BBAax%20gAmwCIwAywAM4wACjjAS4AbwpxVcCawBuwNEgkAuJSrUnGKEEkNSoTAObGTqjVG26DR8o69wzFqzBtGe09vEzQRFmZ-QODQkwAbJh5ouwdHAF8AbQBdNPSKfMpyGjp4JhY2Dm4%20QWFGWQh5DxNnVz1DXn4oIRFxKQb5HIKKKlpoeHDGKTgAIQBXCSY9CWkUW04AXjgACjA5d07akQGJAEpDACkAZQANADoAUXikC2Y4DYA%20ZrUiGDmoRhwAA8Qk0HyBAHpQR8CkA)